# Using complex-valued data in a RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest, complex-numbers

I have a dataset of frequency-domain values, so each element has a `"j"` at the end, like `"27.6695554346-5.51875942715j"`.
this is a pic of some data in the matrix

[image]

When I try to use `RandomForestClassifier` with the following code:

```
cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,n_jobs =5)
cfr.fit(X1,y1)
predictedY2=cfr.predict(X2)
```

I have this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (27.6695554346-5.51875942715j)
```

Could you please explain what I have to do to in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Firstly you should represent your data as complex floats rather than strings (e.g. `X1.astype(np.complex)`)

Comment: X1.astype(np.complex)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required

Comment: What exactly is `X1` and where did it come from? Why does it contain strings in the first place? Based on the error message it looks like the strings it contains have brackets in them, i.e. `"(27.6695554346-5.51875942715j)"` rather than `"27.6695554346-5.51875942715j"` which are preventing numpy from being able to automatically cast them to complex floats. You should not be using strings at all to represent this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

It has to convert them to absolute values
so with just applying np.abs at the matrix the problem solved!